# Setting iTunes category on iOS Enterprise app

Tags: ios, itunes

I've been trying for a while now to preset the iTunes category for an enterprise app to no avail.

Been playing with the iTunesMetaData.plist file hoping that would override the "unknown genre" titling, but can't get it to stick:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
<key>appleId</key>
<string></string>
<key>artistId</key>
<integer>0</integer>
<key>artistName</key>
<string>namehere</string>
<key>buy-only</key>
<true/>
<key>buyParams</key>
<string></string>
<key>copyright</key>
<string></string>
<key>drmVersionNumber</key>
<integer>0</integer>
<key>fileExtension</key>
<string>.app</string>
<key>genre</key>
<string></string>
<key>genreId</key>
<integer>0</integer>
<key>itemId</key>
<integer>0</integer>
<key>itemName</key>
<string>namehere</string>
<key>kind</key>
<string>software</string>
<key>playlistArtistName</key>
<string>namehere</string>
<key>playlistName</key>
<string>namehere</string>
<key>price</key>
<integer>0</integer>
<key>priceDisplay</key>
<string>nil</string>
<key>rating</key>
<dict>
    <key>content</key>
    <string></string>
    <key>label</key>
    <string>4+</string>
    <key>rank</key>
    <integer>100</integer>
 </dict>
<key>releaseDate</key>
<string>Sunday, December 12, 2011</string>
<key>s</key>
<integer>143441</integer>
<key>someicon.png</key>
<string></string>
<key>softwareIconNeedsShine</key>
<false/>
<key>softwareSupportedDeviceIds</key>
<array>
    <integer>1</integer>
</array>
<key>softwareVersionBundleId</key>
<string>com.mycompany.myapp</string>
<key>softwareVersionExternalIdentifier</key>
<integer>0</integer>
<key>softwareVersionExternalIdentifiers</key>
<array>
    <integer>1466803</integer>
    <integer>1529132</integer>
    <integer>1602608</integer>
    <integer>1651681</integer>
    <integer>1750461</integer>
    <integer>1930253</integer>
    <integer>1961532</integer>
    <integer>1973932</integer>
    <integer>2026202</integer>
    <integer>2526384</integer>
    <integer>2641622</integer>
    <integer>2703653</integer>
</array>
<key>vendorId</key>
<integer>0</integer>
<key>versionRestrictions</key>
<integer>0</integer>
</dict>
</plist>
```

I always get the "unknown genre" whenever I add the build to iTunes (I can get the iTunesArtwork image to show up btw).

I've tried with and without all values filled out above, etc.

Maybe I'm just missing something simple?